# Windows Install takes forever to install/uninstall apps

Tags: windows-7, java, windows-installation

Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit - 16GB and SSDs.  I have to install/uninstall various JDK versions.  control panel/programs and features uninstall/install is taking forever - 15-20 minutes. Get "preparing to remove" for most of the time.  Same problem with uninstall other apps also. Disabled Symantec AV.  Task Manger shows 0% CPU.  We also have MalwareBytes installed.  Cannot disable that. Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped/re-started Volume Shadow Copy service and problem fixed.

Comment: Do you mean that you disabled it during the process, or stopped/restarted and then did the process?

Comment: If you stopped the VSS and then made modifications to your system then this might have had the side effect of invalidating any system restore points you had. Not necessarily a bad thing, but just something for future users to bear in mind should they choose this route.